# How to get row numbers from MySQL table?

Tags: php, mysql

So I made table in DB like this for my game's highscore system.

[image]

and I want to get total ROWs number. (at above table, I expect 11 as result)

So I write at .php like,

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $table"; 
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or Die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error()); 
    $info = "";
    while($found = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        $info =  $found;
    }
    echo 'Count'.$info;     exit;
```

and in unity, I receive above echo text and to extract number,

```
 if (hs.text.Contains("Count"))
    {
        string result = Regex.Replace(hs.text, @"\D", "");
        totalHighNum = Int32.Parse(result);
        Debug.Log("total highscore num is " + result);
    }
```

But this does not work. 
Printed echo text says, 'CountArray'

How should I revise?  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must reference the actual column in your result:

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS rowcount FROM $table"; 
$result = mysql_query($sql) or Die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error()); 
$info = "";
if ($found = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $info = $found['rowcount'];
}
echo 'Count'.$info;     
exit;
```

Also, don't use `mysql` extension, it's deprecated, switch to `mysqli`.